# Function with two inputs returns null value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a function that'll calculate sales tax given a state and amount to be taxed. If the state doesn't exist in the SalesTax table the function should return 0. But when I run the function it just returns null value even if the state is in the SalesTax table. What it should return is tax rate (per state that is inputted) * quantity (also input)

```
GO
Create or alter function TaxGivenAState
(@State char(2),@Quantity NUMERIC)
Returns NUMERIC 
as 
BEGIN
    Declare @SalesTaxTotal NUMERIC 
    Declare @TaxRate NUMERIC

    Select @SalesTaxTotal = @TaxRate*@quantity
    From SalesTax s
    Where s.TaxRate = @TaxRate and s.[State]=@State and @TaxRate=s.TaxRate
    If(@SalesTaxTotal=0)
    BEGIN
        Return 0
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        Return @SalesTaxTotal
    END
    return @salestaxtotal
END
```

Comment: Provide an example of your tax table, and a table of expected results.

Comment: `@Quantity NUMERIC` Do you really understand what this does? What are the default values for precision and scale? Are those appropriate for your usage? I often see fractional tax rates - your code does not that. Don't assume - always specify the attributes of datatypes that can vary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't initialised `@TaxRate` with any value, so it is `null` when you multiply it with `@quantity` which will always result in a null:

```
Declare @TaxRate NUMERIC
Select @SalesTaxTotal = @TaxRate*@quantity
```

The `FROM` component has virtuall zero effect here, because you are not using the values from the table at all.

Try this, I've removed the irrelevant aspects of your query

```
GO
Create or alter function TaxGivenAState
(@State char(2),@Quantity NUMERIC)
Returns NUMERIC 
as 
BEGIN
    Declare @SalesTaxTotal NUMERIC 

    Select TOP 1 @SalesTaxTotal = s.TaxRate*@quantity
    From SalesTax s
    Where s.[State]=@State

    return @SalesTaxTotal
END
```

If you wanted to specify the tax type as a parameter, then you should have included that either as a parameter, or provided a query to determine which type of tax rate to use, if you provide a snippet of your tax table we might be able to suggest other areas where you have gone wrong here.